# Next Townhall - the March Meeting

Tags: discussion, townhall

Another townhall time, so please add a suggested date and time between March 15 and March 18 GMT, and if you can attend a time, add your name on to the answer.  That way we can see who best can come.

All times should be in 24 hour GMT.

(yes, the range has changed, to try and allow more people time to come)

Answer (score 2):

**2100 GMT, Friday 15th of March.**

- Mark Mayo
- RoflcoptrException
- hippietrail

Comment: [2100 GMT, Friday 15th of March.](http://permatime.com/UTC/2013-03-15/21:00)

Comment: I'll be travelling :)

Comment: I think I slept through it!

Answer (score 1):

22:00 GMT, Friday March 8th.

HaLaBi

RoflcoptrException

Comment: Seems to be 9am Sydney time tomorrow morning. I would be able to attend for once!

Comment: @hippietrail your maths seems off with these times ;) I'm going to change the question anyway as we haven't had enough people commit to a particular time.

Comment: I used one of those stupid timer converter websites where you can't just paste in `22:00 GMT, Friday March 8th` but have to fiddle with from widgets. Can't we propose times in some better way that doesn't force people to use poorly designed timezone converters? `\-:`

Comment: **[How to suggest dates and times for meetings without forcing people to convert from GMT/UTC?](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/1253)**

Comment: [22:00 GMT, Friday March 8th.](http://permatime.com/UTC/2013-03-08/22:00)

Answer (score -3):

**2100GMT, Thursday March 7th.  Similar time to last time.**

Mark Mayo

Comment: er no it hasn't, but you do raise a good point.  It's a little soon for comfort.  I'm going to tweak the dates in the question.

Comment: [2100GMT, Thursday March 7th.](http://permatime.com/UTC/2013-03-07/21:00)